# How to convert docker stats metrics to the Prometheus supported metrics type?

Tags: docker, prometheus, cadvisor, prometheus-pushgateway, prometheus-python-client

I'm trying to implement a docker monitoring solution in my organization, which will be used for internal monitoring. The problem is the box which is used, does not allow any http port to be exposed due to security reasons and also does not allow to assign networks to any of the containers. As a result, I'm unable to go forward with tools such as cadvisor etc. The only thing working for me is the docker stats command.

Now using this docker stats through API, I want to convert those metrics into a format which is supported by the prometheus, but I'm not sure on how to proceed with this. Once the metrics have been converted, using curl I am planning to push the metrics to a push gateway.

Can someone help me on how to convert this docker stats metrics to prometheus compatible metrics. I will be mainly needing the cpu, memory and disk utilization

P.S: I have heard about the prometheus python client API, but not sure if it can be used in this situation. Any lead on this would be helpful.

Sample docker API output:

```
-bash-5.0# curl   --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://localhost/v1.40/containers/7148f8ea6610/stats?stream=false" |jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3045    0  3045    0     0   1638      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  1637
{
  "read": "2022-04-26T11:25:46.419629339Z",
  "preread": "2022-04-26T11:25:45.416384103Z",
  "pids_stats": {
    "current": 169
  },
  "blkio_stats": {
    "io_service_bytes_recursive": [
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Read",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Write",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Sync",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Async",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Discard",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Total",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Read",
        "value": 11395072
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Write",
        "value": 12288
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Sync",
        "value": 11407360
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Async",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Discard",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Total",
        "value": 11407360
      }
    ],
    "io_serviced_recursive": [
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Read",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Write",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Sync",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Async",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Discard",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 7,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Total",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Read",
        "value": 403
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Write",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Sync",
        "value": 405
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Async",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Discard",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "major": 8,
        "minor": 0,
        "op": "Total",
        "value": 405
      }
    ],
    "io_queue_recursive": [],
    "io_service_time_recursive": [],
    "io_wait_time_recursive": [],
    "io_merged_recursive": [],
    "io_time_recursive": [],
    "sectors_recursive": []
  },
  "num_procs": 0,
  "storage_stats": {},
  "cpu_stats": {
    "cpu_usage": {
      "total_usage": 353478838223345,
      "percpu_usage": [
        177851824458947,
        175627013764398
      ],
      "usage_in_kernelmode": 136092500000000,
      "usage_in_usermode": 213417730000000
    },
    "system_cpu_usage": 2619375300000000,
    "online_cpus": 2,
    "throttling_data": {
      "periods": 0,
      "throttled_periods": 0,
      "throttled_time": 0
    }
  },
  "precpu_stats": {
    "cpu_usage": {
      "total_usage": 353478690297736,
      "percpu_usage": [
        177851810524667,
        175626879773069
      ],
      "usage_in_kernelmode": 136092470000000,
      "usage_in_usermode": 213417620000000
    },
    "system_cpu_usage": 2619373310000000,
    "online_cpus": 2,
    "throttling_data": {
      "periods": 0,
      "throttled_periods": 0,
      "throttled_time": 0
    }
  },
  "memory_stats": {
    "usage": 7378079744,
    "max_usage": 7715459072,
    "stats": {
      "active_anon": 270336,
      "active_file": 2887680,
      "cache": 5001216,
      "dirty": 0,
      "hierarchical_memory_limit": 9223372036854772000,
      "hierarchical_memsw_limit": 9223372036854772000,
      "inactive_anon": 2027520,
      "inactive_file": 2027520,
      "mapped_file": 135168,
      "pgfault": 407636823,
      "pgmajfault": 33,
      "pgpgin": 219693705,
      "pgpgout": 219692076,
      "rss": 2027520,
      "rss_huge": 0,
      "total_active_anon": 1898262528,
      "total_active_file": 2912403456,
      "total_cache": 4865912832,
      "total_dirty": 270336,
      "total_inactive_anon": 454504448,
      "total_inactive_file": 1874886656,
      "total_mapped_file": 324538368,
      "total_pgfault": 16369125632,
      "total_pgmajfault": 13906,
      "total_pgpgin": 7802786212,
      "total_pgpgout": 7801043002,
      "total_rss": 2273120256,
      "total_rss_huge": 0,
      "total_unevictable": 1351680,
      "total_writeback": 540672,
      "unevictable": 0,
      "writeback": 0
    },
    "limit": 16522530816
  },
  "name": "/sample",
  "id": "7148f8ea6610977655a86cad7d4d66103310b8381bfe3fdd6a29235deed43d19"
}
```

Comment: I know you said you cant open any ports, but this theoretically does not open a port, so you can always connect to localhost:9323 (since it does not publish it to IP table).

Worth a try?

https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/prometheus/

Comment: I need to collect data from multiple vm's and make it available in a single instance of prometheus. This solution wont meet my requirements, unless there is a specific way to export the collected prometheus data to a remote prometheus server with all the right labels.

Comment: You can call curl on the http://localhost:9323 as you intended with API, and then when you have "metrics" data saved locally in a file/variable you can push it further as you intended with the API call.

Answer (score 0):

I found a github project which does exactly what you need. Maybe take a look at their source/solution.

- https://github.com/chaddewitt/docker-stats-exporter

Comment: I had a look into it before, but it makes use of flask and I cannot install any other dependencies on my box. I guess it wouldn't suit my scenario.